# Network failure in iOS 12 - `NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=53: Software caused connection abort #4279

Tags: swift, alamofire

Im using `AlamoFire` for network operations.

In case a network operation is executed while the app goes into background (The user clicks the home button)

When the app goes back from background the next request will result in the following error:

`FAILURE: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=53 "Software caused connection abort"`

`UserInfo={_NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <488FE19B-E66B-4562-893D-7498DCB00B84>.<5>,
_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1,
_NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=("LocalDataTask <488FE19B-E66B-4562-893D-7498DCB00B84>.<5>"),
_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=53}`

I can't find a way to reset AlamoFire, URLSession, etc to enable network operations again.

The suggested workaround is using background tasks,

Trying to run the request wrapped in `beginBackgroundTask()` / `beginBackgroundTask()` didn't seem to resolve the issue.

```
var taskId : UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = -1
taskId  = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask {
        UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(taskId)
}

if taskId == -1 {
    return
}

let req = Alamofire.request(...)

req.responseObject {
// using EVReflection to turn response to object
}
UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(taskId)
```

Am I using the background task wrong? Is there a solution to the issue?